# A single table that represents multiple tables

Tags: sql, database, database-design, tree

I have a problem with finding a way to represent multiple tables hash tables into a single table.

Say I have 3 tables with the format:

```
Table1(Table1_PK1,Table1_PK2,Table1_PK3,Table1_Hash)
Table2(Table2_PK1,Table2_PK2,Table2_Hash)
Table3(Table3_Pk1,Table3_PK2,Table3_PK3,Table3_PK4,Table3_PK5,Table3_Hash)
```

`Table1_PK1`,`Table1_PK2`,`Table1_PK3`... are columns and they might have different datatypes (`VARCHAR`, `INT` or `DATETIME` ...).
My question is if there is a way to create a single table (fixed number of columns) that can represent all of these 3 tables (may be more in practical).

I am trying to do this for my database tool. Each table actual a table which contains primary keys and a hash data associating with them.

Comment: Do they have foreign keys, or some way to identify which rows belong together?

Comment: No. All the fields except Hash field in every table are together primary keys (composite primary key).

For example: Table1_PK1,Table1_PK2,Table1_PK3 are Primary Keys in Table1

Comment: Please explain _why_ you want to merge them? There may be better ways of achieving whatever you are trying to achieve...

Answer (score 1):

Since you're apparently building a database tool, not a database, it might make more sense to do this in application code rather than in a database table.

In a different answer, you commented

> I am still looking for a dynamic way to do it without knowing how many primary keys a table can have.

A table can have only one primary key. That primary key can consist of more than one column, though. (You already knew this; you were just using the wrong words, which might confuse others.)

A table can also have an arbitrary number of other keys, which will be either declared (as `NOT NULL UNIQUE`) or "undeclared" (by creating an index that guarantees uniqueness over a set of columns).

You can look *all* that stuff up at run time in one or both of two ways. (Links go to documentation for PostgreSQL.)

- [System tables](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/catalogs.html), sometimes called system catalogs
- [information_schema views](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/information-schema.html)

As far as I know, all modern SQL platforms implement at least one of these interfaces.  The information_schema views are covered in the SQL standards, but there seems to be some room for interpretation. They don't look quite the same on all platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Why combine the 3 tables into one? Would be really bad db design. But here's a way to do it:

The one table will have a column for each of the 3 tables' columns you want in the final table. I am making the assumption that `TableX_Hash` is the same type, so that remains as one unique column:

```
Table_All_in_One (
    Table1_PK1,
    Table1_PK2,
    Table1_PK3,
                    # space just for clarity of grouping
    Table2_PK1,
    Table2_PK2,

    Table3_PK1,
    Table3_PK2,
    Table3_PK3,
    Table3_PK4,
    Table3_PK5,

    TableX_Hash     # Assuming all the _Hash'es are the same type+length,
                    # otherwise, add Table1_Hash, Table2_Hash, Table3_Hash
                    # This can be your new primary key
)
```

The Primary Keys (`PKx`) are required to be non-`NULL` only in their own tables. For this table, they have to allow nulls. **The idea is that each row of this new table will only hold the data for one of the tables. The other columns will be empty for that row.** If you want to associate the row of one table with another, you can add that to the same row or add `FK_Table1_Hash`, `FK_Table2_Hash` and `FK_Table3_Hash` columns which will refer to the `TableX_Hash` value of a record.

PS: I wonder if what you are really looking for is a `View` and not this really bad all-in-one table.

---

Edit: Combining them into one "without knowing how many primary keys a table can have." as per your comment:

Store all the _PKs concatenated into one column:

```
Table_All_in_One (
    New_PK,
    TableX_Hash,

    Table1_PKx,     # Concatenated PKs of Table1
    Table2_PKx,     # Concatenated PKs of Table2, etc.
    ...,
                    # OR just one
    TableX_PKs,     # concatenate all the PK's into one VARCHAR field
                    # Add a pipe `|` between them optionally.
    Table_Num       # If using just one, then you'll need to store the table number
```

)
You will not be able to conveniently pick records based on *part* of their composite primary key. It will always have to be `TableX_PKs = CONCAT_WS('|', Table1_PK1, Table1_PK2, ...)`. So your only dependency is the number of PKs in the original column.

Comment: Thanks for your post, but this not what i am looking for. All of 3 tables are really independent in term of all the fields they have. Lets say if i want to add data of Table10 which has 10 columns of 10 primary keys into Table_All_in_One, this would fail.

Comment: This would work fine even then. You just need to make sure that the `Table_All_in_One` has all the columns of every other table. When you add the data of the 10 columns of table 10 to All_in_One  (`Table10_PK1, _PK2..., PK10`) the remaining columns of All_in_One (`Table2_PK1, Table3_PK5`, etc.) would be empty/`NULL`.

Comment: Hmm... I am still looking for a dynamic way to do it without knowing how many primary keys a table can have.

Answer (score 0):

In order to model a bunch of tables you will need 3 tables.  An entity table that contains the table names of the tables you wish to set up this way called a factor or entity table.  A Factor_detail table that contains all the columns and their associated properties of the tables.  A table, factor_detail_value, for storing things like lookup values for lookup tables.  I'm trying to learn more about this myself as well because we are using this technique at work as well.  Genrate sql on the fly for any table so encoded, and store the data in a repository pertiinant to the data itself.  This way if a table changes and you need to add a column or change a datatype, you can add a row to the factor detail table without affecting a database shut down in production.  In most businesses a four hour shut down to make a sql data table change can cost thousands of dollars.  If you are dealing with insurance for example, each additional state that you sell insurance in has different requirements for being able to seel it and that will result in table changes.  We reduced our table count way down from over 700 tables in this manner also we can make changes without database shut down thus avoiding the loss in revenue.